# Using text file as pattern preg_match_all PHP

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
error:preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 59
```

Hello everyone, I am trying to make a word filter for a client and i have ran into the issue that my code witch is pulling words from a text file can not read the $  character from my text file, mycode is below.

```
 $lines=array();
  $fp=fopen('/opt/lampp/htdocs/Comments/Classes/Bad.txt', 'r');
  while (!feof($fp))
  {
    $line=fgets($fp);
    //process line however you like
    $line=trim($line);
    //add to array
    $lines[] = preg_quote(trim($line));
  }
    fclose($fp);
    $string = Input::get('comments');
    $matches = array();
    $matchFound = preg_match_all(
      "/\b(" . implode("|", $lines) . ")\b/i", 
            $string, 
            $matches
          );
    if ($matchFound) {
      $this->addError("The following is not allowed please change it.");
      $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
      foreach($words as $word) {
        echo "<li>" . $word . "</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably inserting text that happen contains regex metacharacters, and inserting them in such a way that they're actually treated as metachars. You need to `preg_quote()` the text you're inserting to escape all of those metachars.

Comment: So it would would look something like this $line=trim(preg_quote($line));

Comment: don't manipulate the quoted string in any way once it's been quoted. trim() won't do much, but any other manipulations COULD undo the quoting. trim THEN quote.

Comment: I did the preg_quote after the then and it still isnt searching for the special character i may be doing something wrong i updated the code above

Comment: You've got `preg_quote($lines)`, and `$lines` is your array. so you're using an array in string context, and PHP will politely convert that array into the literal word `Array`. try `$lines[] = preg_quote(trim($line))`.

Comment: So i echo the array and found that the line isn't $$ in the array it is \$\$ could that be because of my sanitize function htmlentities(string)($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: $ isn't an html entity. and html entities don't use backslashes. an htmlentity-ified $ would be more like `&#36;`

Comment: `$` is, however, a regex metachar, and after preg_quote would become `\$`.

Comment: could it possibly be my implode ?

Comment: no idea. put your pattern into a string so you can echo it out for inspection.e.g. `$pat = "/\b" . implode(...) . "/"; echo $pat;`

Comment: I have no idea anymore its in the search as a\$\$   (word sensor) and its still not finding it and when i remove the pre_quote so its just a$$ it tells me error at offset 59

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on each line while reading in the text file.